# stop and restart flashing colors in processing

Tags: java, processing

I have the following code that flashes the colors red and white. I want to make a change but I'm not sure how to do. As flashing the two colors be stopped for 3 seconds and begins again.

```
float delay = 1; // 1 frame

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() { 
  background(96);
  fill(255);
  if(frameCount%(2*delay)<delay) fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1

As The Guy with The Hat suggested, you could draw the rectangle only when frameCount%360 < 180

Method 2

Use a timer:

```
float delay = 1; // 1 frame
long n;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  n = millis();
}

void draw() { 
  background(96);
  fill(255);
  if (frameCount%(2*delay)<delay) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  }
  if (millis() - n < 3000) // If 3 seconds haven't yet passed, show the rectangle
  {  
    rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
  }
  else if (millis() - n > 6000) // If 6 seconds have passed, reset timer
  {
    n = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is only draw the rect if `frameCount % 360` is less than `180`:

```
float delay = 1; // 1 frame

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() { 
  background(96);
  fill(255);
  if(frameCount % (2 * delay) < delay) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  }
  if(frameCount % 360 < 180) {
    rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise timer version (its generally a bad idea to use frameCount for timing):

```
void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() { 
  background(96);
  fill(255);
  if (millis()/1000%6<3 && frameCount%2<1)
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
}
```